# Continue script execution after try/except exception with Python

Tags: python

Coming from other scripting languages I'm probably missing something fundamental here.

How do I continue on with the rest of the script when an exception is raised?

Example:

```
errMsg = None
try:
    x = 1
    y = x.non_existent_method()
except ValueError as e:
    errMsg = str(e)

if errMsg:
    print('Error')
else:
    print('All good')
```

The script just fails. Is there a way to continue with the rest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are catching the wrong exception.

Comment: that's embarrassing...it should be Exception and not ValueError. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Exception` and not `ValueError`:

```
errMsg = None
try:
    x = 1
    y = x.non_existent_method()
except Exception as e:
    errMsg = str(e)

if errMsg:
    print('Error')
else:
    print('All good')
```